# Java - Game : Multiple instances

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to make a game in Java, and I've got already something. But i want to make the Player shoot bullets.
I've came up with the idea to make an object array, and put all the Bullet instances into the array. then in a thread, I want to make them all move(all the objects in the array).

This is what I put in the main class:

```
Bullet[] BulletArray;

public int Bullets = 0;

public void run() {

    for(int i = 0; i < Bullets; i++){
        BulletArray[i].Step();
    }

    if(Key.FireKey){
        BulletArray[Bullets + 1] = new Bullet();
        Bullets += 1;
    }
}
```

I've just included the basic stuff, i.e. The run function runs fine, in the original code.
The code doesn't work, it gives me an error when I press Fire. The error is somewhere at

```
BulletArray[Bullets + 1] = new Bullet();
```

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: sorry... what's the question?

Comment: Whats the question? Or you want to inform us that you are making a game?? And FYI., you should declare your variables (to add, methods also) starting with lowercase alphabets, or underscore..

Comment: You should apply Java naming conventions: variables start in small caps: BulletArray => bulletArray, Bullets => bullets etc.

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting a Null Pointer Exception? If so, you can probably fix it by changing the line `BulletArray[Bullets+1] = new Bullet();` to `BulletArray[Bullets] = new Bullet();`

Comment: Do you take care of the array size, i.e. do you increase the size when necessary? If the array should be resizable, I would recommend using a `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters, your `BulletArray` is never initialized.

When you enter `run()`, your `for()` loop appears to work fine because it does not actually enter the block.  Your `int i = 0` is declared and is already greater than or equal to your limit, which is the `int Bullet = 0`.  This means that the body of the loop never executes.

Then, when you press the `Key.FireKey`, it attempts to reference an array index that doesn't exist.  It can't exist, because the array has never been initialized.

To initialize your array, you will need to do something more like this:

```
private int maxBullets = 10;
Bullet[] bulletArray = new Bullet[maxBullets];
```

Then your `for()` loop will actually enter.  Note that in your `Key.FireKey` block, however, that you will have to perform some checking to make sure that you don't get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` by trying to fire more bullets than you've created.  i.e.,

```
if(Key.FireKey) {
    if(bullets < maxBullets) {
        bulletArray[++bullets] = new Bullet();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'm quite new to java, and certainly how it handles arrays.I know the question is kinda stupid, but thanks!

Comment: It's not a stupid question. :)  Everyone has to start somewhere.